# How to get the first elements of each array in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I had one multidimensional array like below. What i like to know is how to extract first array element in each array and construct an array for all first array elements.

```
     Array (
        '0' => Array (
                   'd1' => 'D1',
                   'c1' => 'C1',
                   't1' => 'T1',
                   'a1' => 'A1',
                ),
        '1' =>Array (
                   'd2' => 'D2',
                   'c2' => 'C2',
                   't2' => 'T2',
                   'a2' => 'A2',
                ),
          );
```

After the formatting i need array like the below array.

```
      Array => 
           '0' => Array (
                  'd1' => 'D1',
                  'd2' => 'D2',
                  ),
           '1' => Array (
                  'c1' => 'C1',
                  'c2' => 'C2',
                  ),
           '2' => Array (
                  't1' => 'T1',
                  't2' => 'T2',
                  ),
           '3' => Array (
                  'a1' => 'A1',
                  'a2' => 'A2',
                  ),
        );
```

Comment: so your sorting them by letter?

Comment: nope i am taking each first element in the array and putting them in a new array........the example is like that

Comment: ok what you are asking and what you have given as example are not the same.. so which is which, the one you have in your question or the one in your example?

Comment: Your assuming sorting because of my example. The example is just coincidence to sorting.It's not sorting. I got the answer.

Comment: Hi @Venkat, if any of below answers has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Array (
'0' => Array (
           'd1' => 'D1',
           'c1' => 'C1',
           't1' => 'T1',
           'a1' => 'A1',
        ),
'1' =>Array (
           'd2' => 'D2',
           'c2' => 'C2',
           't2' => 'T2',
           'a2' => 'A2',
        ),
  );


foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($v as $k1=>$v1)
    {
        $b[$i][$k1] = $v1;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
```

Comment: I want each first element in the new array, same like that each second element in the new array and so on........

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array = Array (
    '0' => Array (
       'd1' => 'D1',
       'c1' => 'C1',
       't1' => 'T1',
       'a1' => 'A1',
        ),
     '1' =>Array (
       'd2' => 'D2',
       'c2' => 'C2',
       't2' => 'T2',
       'a2' => 'A2',
       ),
     );
 while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) 
    {
    $i = 0;
      foreach ($value as $key1 => $val1) 
    {
        $array2[$i][$key1] = $val1;
        $i++;
    }
   }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

$user =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [Name] => Kabelo
            [Last_name] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
            [username] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
            [password] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
            [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [Name] => Kgotso
        [Last_name] => Lekula
        [username] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [password] =>5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [Name] => Me
        [Last_name] => White
        [username] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [password] => jsksksh
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [Name] => Hai
        [Last_name] => Black
        [username] => maki@gmail.com
        [password] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [Name] => Tsek
        [Last_name] => Lengitja
        [username] => tebza@make.com
        [password] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [Name] => Akebatle
        [Last_name] => akitsi
        [username] => me@nksjkjshdks.co.za
        [password] => 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [Name] => Jeez
        [Last_name] => motho
        [username] => tjatji@solomzi.com
        [password] => sadasdad
        [reg_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )
```

)

```
            foreach ($user as $key => $value) {

              print_r($user[$key]['Name'];

            }
```